# Composite Index In Servicestack.Ormlite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to create a composite non-unique index in Servicestack's implementation of Ormlite?

For example, a single index that would cover both Field1 and Field2 in that order.

```
public class Poco
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CompositeIndexAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations/CompositeIndexAttribute.cs), e.g:

```
[CompositeIndex("Field1", "Field2")]
public class Poco
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```